# remove "Select image from gallery" option when app starts. Android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity, media

I am a newbie to android.I tried working on an app using some open source code.
The app uses image from gallery and then it is taken into and imageview and we do some operations on the image.

What i need is, the app should start with some default image already into the imageview..then i will add some button to select image from gallery later. I couldnot understand the work flow here. It would be greateful If someone could guide me.

Here is my code main activity.which also contains splash screen.

```
public class Main extends Activity {

static final String PREFS_FILE = "image_edit";

/** The URI of the Image to display. */


private int _wait;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    _wait = 1000;

    imageUri = null;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (_wait != 0) {

        new CountDownTimer(_wait, _wait) {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (imageUri != null) {
                    Intent viewActivity = new Intent(Main.this, Viewer.class);
                    viewActivity.putExtra("image", imageUri);
                    startActivity(viewActivity);
                } else {

                     startActivityForResult(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

        }.start();
        _wait = 0;
    } else {
        if (imageUri != null) {
            Intent viewActivity = new Intent(this, Viewer.class);
            viewActivity.putExtra("image", imageUri);
            startActivity(viewActivity);
        } else {

             startActivityForResult(newIntent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI), 0);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    imageUri = null;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        imageUri = data.getData();
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
        Log.e("result", "BAD");
      }
   }
}
```

Then from here the image taken goes to next activity called Viewer activity whose onresume is this

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mHandler = new Handler();

    mPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(Main.PREFS_FILE, 0);
    setContentView(R.layout.nothing);

    // Inflate all the views.
    int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    basicInit(orientation);
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        initPortrait();

    } else {
        initLandscape();
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri imageURI = null;
    Log.e("URI:", intent.getData() + "");
    if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND)) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras.containsKey(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM)) {
            imageURI = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
        imageURI = intent.getData();
    } else {
        imageURI = (Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra("image");
    }

    addImage(imageURI);

    addDraggableImages();

    _updateImageTask = new UpdateImage(mRelative, mHandler);


   }
```

So i tried doing this in main view where the

```
 if(wait !=0){}
    else{
    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Viewer.class));
    }
```

but this does not work..error is `runtimeexception`

So It would be Helpful if somebody guided me..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in onResume() method of your MainActivity first it will go to the else part i.e startActivityForResult that will open up a gallery and ask you to pick up an image.

Instead of putting this into onResume,you can simple create a button in main_screen.xml

and then implement this functionality in onclickListener of that button.

To see an image by default,in the Imageview tag of your xml you can put this: android:src="@drawable/imageFile"

Does it make sense to you?

Answer (score 0):

Below is given Java class and laoyout file similar to app that you are talking about.

MainActivity.java

```
      package com.tag.photocaptureandgallery;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.provider.MediaStore;
    import android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.ImageView;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final int SELECT_FILE = 1;
private final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private ImageView ivImage;
private Button btnSetImage;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    btnSetImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);

    btnSetImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });

}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
            "Cancel" };

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File f = new File(android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                        SELECT_FILE);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    .toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            try {
                Bitmap bm;
                BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath(),
                        btmapOptions);

                // bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 70, 70, true);
                ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);

                String path = android.os.Environment
                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + File.separator
                        + "Phoenix" + File.separator + "default";
                f.delete();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, String.valueOf(System
                        .currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                try {
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String tempPath = getPath(selectedImageUri, MainActivity.this);
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tempPath, btmapOptions);
            ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri, Activity activity) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = activity
            .managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

}

Main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Photo" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Also add necessary permissions for using Camera.